# Cannot get new icons working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: icons, gnome-tweak-tool, icon-themes, faenza

I have installed several icon sets, e.g. [faenza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt5Hc.png) via [the equinox PPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkQVZ.png).
However, they do not appear in GNOME Tweaks > Appearance > Icons.

[image]

I have done both <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and reboot, still not showing.

I cannot activate/use them. There is not really much that can be done wrong when installing them via PPA. So what am I missing?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGK9j.gif I have just installed `sudo apt install faenza-icon-theme` with out PPA and it is working like this..

Comment: Which PPA are you using?

Comment: I have done both, ALT F2 + R and reboot. Not showing.

Comment: This shows it is installed: https://i.imgur.com/MTyMRSo.png  and this shows that no other than the standard icon packs are listed in Gnome Tweaks: https://i.imgur.com/6KM0aoX.png

Comment: Using the equinox PPA https://i.imgur.com/CTJFa5g.png

Comment: Please note that you should always [edit] your question and add relevant info. Comments section is not a safe place for that as comments tend to get overlooked (and even deleted) for various reasons.

Comment: Do you get some errors when you do `sudo apt update`? This PPA was last updated for Trusty (14.04). There is no release for Cosmic (18.10). Also, what is the output of  `apt list --installed | grep faenza; ls -l /usr/share/icons/Faenza `?

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem related to permissions.

This output shows the folders exist but as you can see they are not accessible by users other than root.

```
drwx------ 11 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza-Ambiance/
drwx------  9 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza-Dark/
drwx------  5 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza-Darker/
drwx------  5 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza-Darkest/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Mar 20 17:07 Faenza-Radiance/
```

Change the rights of the folders by executing the command `sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/share/icons/Faenza` and restart GNOME shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. faenza now shows in icon themes.